# the rational canonical

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let T$\in$ $\mathcal{L}$($\mathbb{Q^3}$,$\mathbb{Q^3}$) be given by $$T(v)= 
\left[
\matrix
{
1&-1&-4 \\
1&-1&-3 \\
-1&2&-2   
}
\right]v
$$ . Find the rational canonical form of T.

let $$ A= 
\left[
\matrix
{
1&-1&-4 \\
1&-1&-3 \\
-1&2&-2   
}
\right]$$

The first thing I did which finding the characteristics equation  $-(1+x)(x^2+x+1)$ and characteristic polynomial$=-(I+A)(I+A^2+A)$
then I did invariant factor decomposition .

I am wondering how would I determine the  possibilities for the minimal polynomial? and what is the next step 
would someone check my work?

Comment: given you have the characteristic polynomial down to its irreducible factors, the minimal polynomial will always have exactly the same irreducible factors to a multiplicity less than or equal to the multiplicity in the characteristic polynomial. e.g. if $\chi_A = (x-\lambda_1)^{m_1}(x-\lambda_2)^{m_2}\ldots$, you'll have $\mu_a = (x-\lambda_1)^{n_1}(x-\lambda_2)^{n_2}\ldots$ with $n_i \leq m_i$ for all $i$. Then you just check which one is the one with the smallest overall degree that works.

Comment: and notice that the minimal polynomial is unique: If you have one polynomial of degree $n$ that works, there is no other one of the same degree that also works.

Comment: so my minimal polynomial is $(x+1)$ ?

Comment: Did you check? Does that work?

Comment: I should have made it clearer that over $\mathbb{Q}$ polynomials do not necessarily factor into linear terms. In fact, in your example, they don't. The strategy is still the same, though.

Comment: how would I check that. Would you give me a hint ?

Comment: Well, how is the minimal polynomial defined?

Answer (score 1):

The minimal polynomial will have all the irreducible factors of the characteristic polynomials as factors and also divides the characteristic polynomial. Therefore in this case the minimal polynomial must be the characteristic polynomial.

The definition of the minimal polynomial is it is the smallest degree monic polynomial that the matrix satisfies. Because polynomial rings over a field are principal ideal domains, the minimal polynomial divides any polynomial that the matrix satisfies (the set of polynomials that the matrix satisfies is an ideal and this ideal is generated by the minimal polynomial).

The Cayley-Hamilton Theorem says that $A$ satisfies the characteristic polynomial of $A$. So the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides the characteristic polynomial of $A$ (by the above facts). It is not hard to show that each irreducible factor of the characteristic polynomial also divides the minimal polynomial (although with potentially different multiplicities).